# Optimizing a convex combination

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Assume that functions $f_i:X\to\mathbb{R}$ are fixed among weights $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ with $\sum_i \alpha_i=1$, and assume that each function $f_i$ is maximized at a point $x_i\in X$, i.e. $\sup_x f_i (x)=f_i(x_i)$. What can we say about the maximum of the convex combination $f(x)=\alpha_1f_1(x)+...+\alpha_n f_n(x)$? Could someone refer me to literature that would address questions like these? In particular, what properties would we want to require from each function $f_i$ for this maximization to be possible given the above assumptions.

Comment: I guess: not much without further assumptions on the $f_i$ or under strong assumptions on the $x_i$. The problem to determine the maximum of $f_1(x)/2+f_2(x)/2$ is already pretty tough

Comment: @Surb: That is exactly the question: what properties would we want to require from each function $f_i$. I'm sure there are many different options, but if there is any literature that discusses this scenario, or if someone knows from the top of their head, I would really appreciate the input.

Comment: well... If $f_i=f_j$ or $x_i=x_j$ for all $i,j$ then it's quite easy :).

Comment: Id guess if each $f_i$ was only a function of an orthogonal coordinate...

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist. Not sure what you mean by that. Each $f_{i}$ is a function of the same variable. I've edited this to the question to make it more clear. This variable could be another function, a sequence of functions, a sequence of numbers, or anything else. We can assume that $X$ is a vector space for simplicity or a convex subset of such.

Comment: Your title says "convex combination" but your question says nothing about the  $\alpha_i$ being nonnegative.  Assuming $\alpha_i\geq 0$, we see immediately that $\sup_{x \in X} \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i f_i(x)$ is bounded and is at most $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i f_i(x_i)$.  What do you mean "for this maximization to be possible"?  You need very mild assumptions for the supremum to be achievable, such as the function $\sum_i \alpha_i f_i(x)$ is continuous and the set $X$ is compact.  Do you really mean that you want the maximizer of $\sum_i \alpha_i f_i(x)$ to be some nice function of the $x_i$?

Comment: @michael. Yes. The supremum will be finite and the maximum will exist with quite mild assumptions. But I would like the maximizer to be some nice function of $x_i$, if that's possible.

Comment: Not possible in general, as knowing $x_i$ maximizes $f_i(x)$ essentially tells you no useful info.  The @BenjaminLindqvist comment is a good answer for a special case.

Comment: @michael. I know there is no answer in general, it's easy to produce counter examples even in $\mathbb{R}$, but it's also easy to find classes of functions for which it is possible, if the assumptions are strong enough. In the question I was asking for reference to literature where such problems are addressed, unless someone knows from the top of their head. Also, regarding Benjamin's post, each function is fully dependent on the same variable, most likely some nice function space in the context of my interest or the hilbert cube. But we definitely don't have an inner product in the domain.

Comment: Take $x =(y,z_1, ..., z_n)$ and for all $i\in\{1, ..., n\}$  take $f_i(x) = g(y) + h_i(z_i)$ for any functions $g(y)$ and $h_1(z_1), ..., h_n(z_n)$.   This is a modest generalization of Benjamin's example.